# Rails tests fail for no real reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I'm trying to get started with tests in Rails, I'm trying to add tests to a project I've been working on for some time.

You can see the results of the test here: http://travis-ci.org/#!/dannymcc/BaseApp2/builds/253987

As such, there aren't really any tests in place - so shouldn't it pass automatically?

You can see the fixture code etc. here: https://github.com/dannymcc/BaseApp2

I am working my way through the Rails testing guide but I thought it would pass until I write a test that fails? (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Comment: from your link, I just see you should migrate your db

Comment: Your test run is failing because several database migrations are pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the migrations as it suggests?

Comment: This is what I don't understand - if I run the local migrations and then push - does that mean I need to commit in the sqlite database to the repo?

Comment: No, generally you don't want to replicate as-is data across remote servers, your sqlite files shouldn't be in your db. For example, one of my apps: https://github.com/agmcleod/PhoneQA/tree/master/db. The idea is to keep development and production data completely separate. If there's core data an application requires to run, like a default admin account, look into using the seed data for that. just make sure you run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` before you run the tests on your dev environment and that should do it.

Comment: No problem. More or less, storing lots of data on a git repository can eat up your space really quickly. So long as the schema, which defines the tables & columns of the database is with the repo, you'll be fine at keeping the structure up to date for every machine that pulls to that repository.